# Assert.IsNotNull(...) - VS 2010 Which reference do I need to Add?

Tags: c#, reference, assert

I am not sure if this is a bug or my installation is completely missing a DLL. 
I need to use ASSERT in C#, so I need add ther reference for `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;`

But the DLL referencing to is missing. I am pointing towards the wrong DLL in VS 2010?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.dll`.  The type's *namespace* is `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`, but the assembly in which the type is defined has a different name.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243773%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), the name of the assembly is "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework"; its DLL is `microsoft.visualstudio.qualitytools.unittestframework.dll`.

Comment: Well using opensource code. So had no idea that the names was incorrect all together. Nevertheless. Thanks. Solved my problem. Cheers!

Comment: @Wajih the name is not incorrect.  The *namespace* is `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`; the name of the assembly is not always the same as the namespace.  I edited the answer to clarify.

Comment: There is a `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.dll` actually

Comment: @HristoYankov Would you care to elaborate?  Where is it?

Comment: @phog well, it's some old DLL by Microsoft. We do have it in our solution and I was googling it, that's how I came across this post.

Comment: @HristoYankov interesting. I notice that the current name of the dll in the link in this answer is `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll`, so I suppose they like to rename it from time to time. I suppose `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.dll` was probably the original name.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `Debug.Assert`, you need to reference `System.Diagnostics`.

You do mean regular Assert to use in classes, right, or do you mean unit-test Assert? The latter would require a reference to the `microsoft.visualstudio.qualitytools.unittestframework.dll`, if you use MsTest instead of another framework such as NUnit.